# Undefined variable with class

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to do a dynamic query building with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12152307/9334297) but apparently, I'm missing something out:

When I do `$db->select($fields,$where, $params);`, it returns undefined variable on db.

Please, don't mind the unparameterized query as I can't find a way to fix that (maybe I'll do another question).

Here goes my code so far:

db_connection:

```php
<?php

$servername = ""; // credentials removed
$username = "";
$password = "";
$database =  "";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$servername;Database=$database", $username, $password);

    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   //echo "Connected successfully\n";
    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    //echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

readRecords.php

```php
include 'db_connection.php';
        // Recolher dados POST

        class db {

            public $conn;

            public function select($fields = '', $where = '1', $params = array(), $limit = '') { //fetchArgs, etc
                //$fields = implode(', ', $this->dbFields);

                //create query
                $query = "SELECT $fields FROM $databaseInUse WHERE $where $limit";

                //prepare statement
                $stmt = $this->conn->query($query);

                return $stmt->execute($params);

                //$stmt->fetchAll($fetchStyle);
            }
            //...
        }


        date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Lisbon");

        $secondDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+1 day", strtotime((String)$dataInit)));

        try
        {
            $fields = "MAX(DATEPART(hh,Datetime)) AS hora, COUNT(ID) AS prod";
            $where = "DateTime > '".$dataInit." 00:00' 
            AND DateTime < '".$dataInit." 16:30' 
            AND GlobalResult=1

            GROUP BY DATEPART(hh,Datetime);";
            $params = "";
            $db->select($fields,$where, $params);

/*          $sql= $conn->prepare("SELECT MAX(DATEPART(hh,Datetime)) AS hora, COUNT(ID) AS prod

            FROM $databaseInUse

            WHERE DateTime > '".$dataInit." 00:00' 
            AND DateTime < '".$dataInit." 16:30' 
            AND GlobalResult=1

            GROUP BY DATEPART(hh,Datetime);");

            //$sql->bindValue(':database', $databaseInUse);
            $sql->execute(); */



        }

        catch (PDOException $e){echo $e->getMessage();
```

Comment: Where have you initialized `$this->conn`? Its not in the class youve posted.

Comment: Well, this is not the most updated code but I already tried doing `public $conn` with no success

Comment: `$this->$conn` is not right, should be `$this->conn`

Comment: @Qirel fixed, same output

Comment: Just by looking at the code, `$db` is also undefined. Without you telling us *which variables are undefined*, its a guessing-game for us. Consult the duplicate for detailed information about these kinds of errors.

Comment: @Qirel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57303932/undefined-variable-with-class#comment101101963_57304433

Comment: Well, I figured it out, thanks, the canonical question helped me!

Answer (score 0):

You use the `$db` variable in readRecords.php, but it has not been defined anywhere. Neither in this file nor in any of your other files you've posted.

There are many strange things in your code anyway, so it does not surprise me that it does not work (a miracle that it even works).

The `$conn` property in your class `db` is not initialisied anywhere. Your select method will attempt to access the $conn property dynamic (under your comment "// prepare statement"). Did you mean  `$this->conn->query...` instead?

Comment: As mentioned, I followed the linked question method, isn't `$db->select($fields,$where, $params);` supposed to call the class function?

Comment: @CaldeiraG It does, and then you are accessing and undefined property `$conn` which actually is the error and the cause. You have never initialised `$conn`.

Comment: @CodeSpirit thank you! I managed to fix it, based on a question in the duplicate chain of questions and realized that.